# My mail server seems to be sending out spam and I am trying to find the cause

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, postfix, sendmail, dovecot, mail-server

I have a mail server hosted with amazon aws.

I setup the server on Ubuntu 14.04 with postfix & dovecot.

I keep getting emails from mail delivery system saying mails are returned to sender that I did not send.

I have 2fa setup on my domain provider and my ec2 server and to log in I only have ssh port configured to be open to a specific IP. Also I have key based log-in setup as well so only the owner of the key can access the server while being registered at a specific IP and logging in with only 1 username that isn't as standard one.

Looking at my syslog I have taken out a small section that concerns me

```
Dec  7 21:25:16 ip-myip postfix/smtpd[14438]: Anonymous TLS connection established from dazzle.jagoanhosting.com[103.27.206.196]: TLSv1     with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits)
Dec  7 21:25:17 ip-myip postfix/smtp[14490]: connect to mx1.comcast.net[96.114.157.80]:25: Connection timed out
Dec  7 21:25:17 ip-ip-myip postfix/smtp[14490]: connect to mx1.comcast.net[2001:558:fe16:1b::15]:25: Network is unreachable
Dec  7 21:25:18 ip-ip-myip postfix/smtpd[14438]: 0E5EB2614C: client=dazzle.jagoanhosting.com[103.27.206.196], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=support@myserver.com
Dec  7 21:25:18 ip-ip-myip postfix/cleanup[14441]: 0E5EB2614C: message-id=<81233e02b1004e7178eab89587879deb@www.thamesjakarta.com>
Dec  7 21:25:18 ip-ip-myip postfix/qmgr[1176]: 0E5EB2614C: from=<support@phoneunlockserver.com>, size=1734, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec  7 21:25:19 ip-ip-myip postfix/smtpd[14438]: disconnect from dazzle.jagoanhosting.com[103.27.206.196]
Dec  7 21:25:22 ip-ip-myip postfix/smtp[14444]: connect to mta7.am0.yahoodns.net[98.136.216.25]:25: Connection timed out
Dec  7 21:25:22 ip-ip-myip postfix/smtp[14444]: 443D526141: to=<malston73@yahoo.com>, relay=none, delay=151, delays=0.68/0/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mta7.am0.yahoodns.net[98.136.216.25]:25: Connection timed out)
```

Like I said that is a small section and there is loads of lines just  like that

The thing that confused me first that all the returned emails I got referenced email addresses that I had received mail from at some point and I cannot believe that that is a coincidence.

I am wondering if there is anyone that can help me figure out the issue or at least point me in the right direction

Update..

The last returned mail I have says

```
From:
Mail Delivery System Mailer-Daemon@server13.larsa-hosting.com
To:
support@myserver.com
Subject:
Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender
Body:
This message was created automatically by mail delivery software. 

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its 
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed: 

  TomTom-GB@email.tomtommailer.com 
    Domain larsa.nl has exceeded the max defers and failures per hour (5/5 (100%)) allowed. Message discarded. 
  seomega01@gmail.com 
    Domain larsa.nl has exceeded the max defers and failures per hour (5/5 (100%)) allowed. Message discarded. 
  codes@gsmfather.com 
    Domain larsa.nl has exceeded the max defers and failures per hour (5/5 (100%)) allowed. Message discarded. 
  ramya.a@zohocorp.com 
    Domain larsa.nl has exceeded the max defers and failures per hour (5/5 (100%)) allowed. Message discarded. 
  announcements-bounces@owncloud.org 
    Domain larsa.nl has exceeded the max defers and failures per hour (5/5 (100%)) allowed. Message discarded.
```

Now from the from address that would assume to me that nothing is wrong and the mail isn't actually being sent from my server but the addresses that have been mailed are pretty specific to mail addresses I would have received from. It is pretty random that someone would be able to guess at least 4 of them addresses at random

EDIT 2

I just checked postqueue -p and returned this. I've only included the ones from the last day but there is loads there

```
ECE6A2EBD6     1449 Sun Dec 11 17:16:39  support@myserver.com
                (connect to mx.ono.com[62.42.230.22]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         pacofj@ono.com

E9A7E2CDBC     1625 Sun Dec 11 04:40:35  support@myserver.com
            (connect to mx01.1and1.es[217.72.192.67]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         moncho@ventairdistribucion.com

EE2532CF3A     1604 Sun Dec 11 00:00:10  support@myserver.com
(delivery temporarily suspended: connect to mx3.hotmail.com[65.55.37.104]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         abobaker1212@hotmail.com

EE15D2C1B6     1474 Sat Dec 10 02:57:23  support@myserver.com
(delivery temporarily suspended: connect to mx3.hotmail.com[104.44.194.235]:25: Connection timed out)
                                     roguerito@hotmail.com

-- 67941 Kbytes in 27611 Requests.
```

Could this be actual emails being sent from my server?

I have deleted all mail from the mail queue using postsuper -d ALL

Thank you

Comment: I don't see at evidence that anyone logged into your system.  A connection was established and disconnected within 3 seconds, this connection, no user authentication happened in those 3 seconds.  Verify your running the current version of all packages though.

Comment: Is there anything else I could check to see if anyone is sending spam some other way?

Comment: This will happen if someone is sending out faked emails *from some other mail server* which have your mail server in the from address.

Comment: Thank you, Is there any way to stop it or make certain that this is definitely the case?

Comment: @Jinx13 You can't stop it unless you can find the persons responsible and explain with extreme prejudice that you do not appreciate their behaviour/report them to some authority in their country. All that needs to happen for someone to get the email addresses is to buy a list of them from some other despicable outfit, or just randomly generate lots of email addresses. *Other answers may be more complete and accurate.*